# Web Scraping Python, error 503, как обойти?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-scraping, bs4

Пытаюсь с помощью BS4 + Requests попасть на сайт https://bhf.io/
Но вылетает ошибка 503 на гет - запросе:

```
requests.get('URL', headers=header)
header = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}
blacklist_bhf = 'https://bhf.io/forums/137/'
def beautifulsoup(url_content):
    return BeautifulSoup(url_content, 'lxml')
page_bhf = requests.get(blacklist_bhf, headers=header) # error 503 here
print(page_bhf)
soup = beautifulsoup(page_bhf.content)
```

Может, кто - то подсказать, пожалуйста, как можно это обойти? Желательно с примером.

Comment: На входе сайта стоит защита от DDoS. Видимо просто подмена user agent не убедила ее, что ваш скрипт - это браузер)

Comment: @insolor: 5xx ошибка указывает на проблему с сервером. 4xx на проблему с запросом. Есть примеры, когда 503 ошибка используется для rate limiting (можно попробовать реже запросы делать, закэшировать на диск запрос на время).

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось с вашим кодом зайти на страницу и получить `response code 200`.
Но в `header` необходимо сделать небольшое изменение:

```
header = {
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    #'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br', # удалите эту строку
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.8',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36'
}
```

Удаление параметра `accept-encoding` нужно для предотвращения появления кракозябр в возвращаемом `page_bhf`.

Теперь по поводу ошибки 503 - скорее всего вы ее ловите из-за частого обращения к сайту в цикле или что-то типа этого.
Я уже отвечал на подобный вопрос [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45194803/5908433).
В подобной ситуации я обходил эту проблему внедрением случайной и относительно долгой паузы между запросами:

```
import time
import numpy as np

time.sleep((30-5)*np.random.random()+5) #from 5 to 30 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

503 ошибка прилетает иногда, когда сервер противится парсингу, в моём случае часто помогает опция скрытия информации о парсинге. Пример для selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) "\
    "AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) "\
    "Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36")
options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features")
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled') 

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.execute_script("Object.defineProperty(navigator, 'webdriver', {get: () => undefined})")
driver.get(url)
```